# Seeing wierd stripes when trying to install kali linux

Tags: linux, kali-linux, usb, grub

I tried to install kali linux on my HP probook 450. While trying to install i experienced some wired artifacts

[image: Wired artifacts]

but if I choose Live mode then everything works just fine.

Comment: what is the point of posting your observations if you do not ask a question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The picture shows your display device has lost synchronization with the output of your video display adapter.

The classical solution is, when the GRUB menu appears, edit the first option, following the onscreen instructions, and add the parameter *nomodeset* to the line which launches Linux.  https://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/sln306327/manual-nomodeset-kernel-boot-line-option-for-linux-booting?lang=en provides an illustration of how to do that.

- Watch for the "GNU GRUB" bootloader screen.
- When you see the option for your OS, press the "E" key on your keyboard.
- In the editor, use the arrow keys to locate the end of the line that starts
  with "linux /boot/vmlinuz***" (each bootloader may say something
  slightly different).
- Type the "nomodeset" line option into the line near the end.
- Press "CTRL+X" keys and your system should boot without this problem.

A permanent solution, if this works, is also shown therein.